# How to create html tag with arbitrary attribute?

Tags: html

I wan to create a html tag: `<div ng-app></div>`, I try to use `document.createElement('div')` to create the `div` tag, but I don't know how to add `ng-app` to the `div` tag.

The function `element.setAttribute(key, value)` doesn't fit my flavor here.

Comment: Why `element.setAttribute(key, value)` function doesn't fit your flavor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass an empty string as the second parameter for setAttribute.

```js
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
div.setAttribute('ng-app','');
```

```html
<div>Testing</div>
```